# Single kafka consumer listening to multiple kafka queue

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka I am using 1 Kafka broker (0.10.2) and 1 zookeeper (3.4.9). I have two topics with five partitions each. I am running one consumer and in the consumer.subscribe command I have passed both the topic as a list.

> kafkaConsumer.subscribe([topic1,topic2] , new HandleRebalance())

but according to my observation, this consumer is consuming message from only one topic continuously and when that topic doesn't contain any messages then it switches to the next topic. Is it possible that the consumer listens to both the partition in a balanced way?

Note:  By the balanced way I meant that suppose for 10 sec it consumes from topic1 and then it switches to topic2.

Consumer Code :

```
import com.mongodb.DBObject
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRebalanceListener
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndMetadata
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetCommitCallback
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import java.util.regex.Pattern
class KafkaPollingConsumer implements Runnable {
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaPollingConsumer.class)
            private static final String TAG = "[KafkaPollingConsumer]"
            private final KafkaConsumer<String, byte []> kafkaConsumer
            private Map<TopicPartition,OffsetAndMetadata> currentOffsetsMap = new HashMap<>()
            List topicNameList
            Map kafkaTopicConfigMap = new HashMap<String,Object>()
            Map kafkaTopicMessageListMap = new HashMap<String,List>()

            public KafkaPollingConsumer(String serverType, String groupName, String topicNameRegex){
                logger.debug("{} [Constructor] [Enter] Thread Name {} serverType group Name TopicNameRegex",TAG,Thread.currentThread().getName(),serverType,groupName,topicNameRegex)
                logger.debug("Populating Property for kafak consumer")
                Properties kafkaConsumerProperties = new Properties()
                kafkaConsumerProperties.put("group.id", groupName)
                kafkaConsumerProperties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
                kafkaConsumerProperties.put("value.deserializer", "com.custom.kafkaconsumer.deserializer.CustomObjectDeserializer")
                switch(serverType){
                    case KafkaTopicConfigEntity.KAFKA_NODE_TYPE_ENUM.Priority.toString() :
                        kafkaConsumerProperties.put("bootstrap.servers",ConfigLoader.conf.kafkaServer.priority.kafkaNode)
                        kafkaConsumerProperties.put("enable.auto.commit",ConfigLoader.conf.kafkaServer.priority.consumer.enable.auto.commit)
                        kafkaConsumerProperties.put("auto.offset.reset",ConfigLoader.conf.kafkaServer.priority.consumer.auto.offset.reset)
                        break
                    case KafkaTopicConfigEntity.KAFKA_NODE_TYPE_ENUM.Bulk.toString() :
                        kafkaConsumerProperties.put("bootstrap.servers",ConfigLoader.conf.kafkaServer.bulk.kafkaNode)
                        kafkaConsumerProperties.put("enable.auto.commit",ConfigLoader.conf.kafkaServer.bulk.consumer.enable.auto.commit)
                        kafkaConsumerProperties.put("auto.offset.reset",ConfigLoader.conf.kafkaServer.bulk.consumer.auto.offset.reset)
                        kafkaConsumerProperties.put("max.poll.records",10)
                        kafkaConsumerProperties.put("max.poll.interval.ms",900000)
                        kafkaConsumerProperties.put("request.timeout.ms",900000)
                        break
                    default :
                        throw "Invalid server type"
                        break
                }
                logger.debug("{} [Constructor] KafkaConsumer Property Populated {}",properties.toString())
                kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, byte []>(kafkaConsumerProperties)
                topicNameList = topicNameRegex.split(Pattern.quote('|'))
                logger.debug("{} [Constructor] Kafkatopic List {}",topicNameList.toString())
                logger.debug("{} [Constructor] Exit",TAG)
            }

            private class HandleRebalance implements ConsumerRebalanceListener {
                public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                }

                public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                    if(currentOffsetsMap != null && !currentOffsetsMap.isEmpty()) {
                        logger.debug("{} In onPartitionsRevoked Rebalanced ",TAG)
                        kafkaConsumer.commitSync(currentOffsetsMap)
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            void run() {
                logger.debug("{} Starting Thread ThreadName {}",TAG,Thread.currentThread().getName())
                populateKafkaConfigMap()
                initializeKafkaTopicMessageListMap()
                String topicName
                String consumerClassName
                String consumerMethodName
                Boolean isBatchJob
                Integer batchSize = 0
                final Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread()
                Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        logger.error("{},gracefully shutdowning thread {}",TAG,mainThread.getName())
                        kafkaConsumer.wakeup()
                        try {
                            mainThread.join()
                        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                            logger.error("{} Error : {}",TAG,exception.getStackTrace().join("\n"))
                        }
                    }
                })
                kafkaConsumer.subscribe(topicNameList , new HandleRebalance())
                try{
                    while(true){
                        logger.debug("{} Starting Consumer with polling time in ms 100",TAG)
                        ConsumerRecords kafkaRecords = kafkaConsumer.poll(100)
                        for(ConsumerRecord record: kafkaRecords){
                            topicName = record.topic()
                            DBObject kafkaTopicConfigDBObject = kafkaTopicConfigMap.get(topicName)
                            consumerClassName = kafkaTopicConfigDBObject.get(KafkaTopicConfigEntity.CLASS_NAME_KEY)
                            consumerMethodName = kafkaTopicConfigDBObject.get(KafkaTopicConfigEntity.METHOD_NAME_KEY)
                            isBatchJob = kafkaTopicConfigDBObject.get(KafkaTopicConfigEntity.IS_BATCH_JOB_KEY)
                            logger.debug("Details about Message")
                            logger.debug("Thread {}",mainThread.getName())
                            logger.debug("Topic {}",topicName)
                            logger.debug("Partition {}",record.partition().toString())
                            logger.debug("Offset {}",record.offset().toString())
                            logger.debug("clasName {}",consumerClassName)
                            logger.debug("methodName {}",consumerMethodName)
                            logger.debug("isBatchJob {}",isBatchJob.toString())
                            if(isBatchJob == true){
                                batchSize = Integer.parseInt(kafkaTopicConfigDBObject.get(KafkaTopicConfigEntity.BATCH_SIZE_KEY).toString())
                                logger.debug("batchSize {}",batchSize.toString())
                            }
                            Object message = record.value()
                            logger.debug("message {}",message.toString())
                            publishMessageToConsumers(consumerClassName,consumerMethodName,isBatchJob,batchSize,message,topicName)
                            Thread.sleep(60000)
                            currentOffsetsMap.put(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()),new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset() +1))
                        }
                        logger.debug("{} Commiting Messages to Kafka",TAG)
                        kafkaConsumer.commitSync(currentOffsetsMap)
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptException exception){
                    logger.error("{} In InterruptException",TAG)
                    logger.error("{} Exception {}",TAG,exception.getStackTrace().join("\n"))
                }
                catch (WakeupException exception) {
                    logger.error("{} In WakeUp Exception",TAG)
                    logger.error("{} Exception {}",TAG,exception.getStackTrace().join("\n"))
                }
                catch(Exception exception){
                    logger.error("{} In Exception",TAG)
                    logger.error("{} Exception {}",TAG,exception.getStackTrace().join("\n"))
                }
                finally {
                    logger.error("{} In finally commiting remaining offset ",TAG)
                    publishAllKafkaTopicBatchMessages()
                    kafkaConsumer.commitSync(currentOffsetsMap)
                    kafkaConsumer.close()
                    logger.error("{} Exiting Consumer",TAG)
                }
            }


    private void publishMessageToConsumers(String consumerClassName,String consumerMethodName,Boolean isBatchJob,Integer batchSize,Object message, String topicName){
        logger.debug("{} [publishMessageToConsumer] Enter",TAG)
        if(isBatchJob == true){
            publishMessageToBatchConsumer(consumerClassName, consumerMethodName,batchSize, message, topicName)
        }
        else{
            publishMessageToNonBatchConsumer(consumerClassName, consumerMethodName, message)
        }
        logger.debug("{} [publishMessageToConsumer] Exit",TAG)
    }

    private void publishMessageToNonBatchConsumer(String consumerClassName, String consumerMethodName, message){
        logger.debug("{} [publishMessageToNonBatchConsumer] Enter",TAG)
        executeConsumerMethod(consumerClassName,consumerMethodName,message)
        logger.debug("{} [publishMessageToNonBatchConsumer] Exit",TAG)
    }

    private void publishMessageToBatchConsumer(String consumerClassName, String consumerMethodName, Integer batchSize, Object message, String topicName){
        logger.debug("{} [publishMessageToBatchConsumer] Enter",TAG)
        List consumerMessageList = kafkaTopicMessageListMap.get(topicName)
        consumerMessageList.add(message)
        if(consumerMessageList.size() == batchSize){
            logger.debug("{} [publishMessageToBatchConsumer] Pushing Messages In Batches",TAG)
            executeConsumerMethod(consumerClassName, consumerMethodName, consumerMessageList)
            consumerMessageList.clear()
        }
        kafkaTopicMessageListMap.put(topicName,consumerMessageList)
        logger.debug("{} [publishMessageToBatchConsumer] Exit",TAG)
    }

    private void populateKafkaConfigMap(){
        logger.debug("{} [populateKafkaConfigMap] Enter",TAG)
        KafkaTopicConfigDBService kafkaTopicConfigDBService = KafkaTopicConfigDBService.getInstance()
        topicNameList.each { topicName ->
            DBObject kafkaTopicDBObject = kafkaTopicConfigDBService.findByTopicName(topicName)
            kafkaTopicConfigMap.put(topicName,kafkaTopicDBObject)
        }
        logger.debug("{} [populateKafkaConfigMap] kafkaConfigMap {}",TAG,kafkaTopicConfigMap.toString())
        logger.debug("{} [populateKafkaConfigMap] Exit",TAG)
    }

    private void initializeKafkaTopicMessageListMap(){
        logger.debug("{} [initializeKafkaTopicMessageListMap] Enter",TAG)
        topicNameList.each { topicName ->
            kafkaTopicMessageListMap.put(topicName,[])
        }
        logger.debug("{} [populateKafkaConfigMap] kafkaTopicMessageListMap {}",TAG,kafkaTopicMessageListMap.toString())
        logger.debug("{} [initializeKafkaTopicMessageListMap] Exit",TAG)
    }

    private void executeConsumerMethod(String className, String methodName, def messages){
        try{
            logger.debug("{} [executeConsumerMethod] Enter",TAG)
            logger.debug("{} [executeConsumerMethod] className  {} methodName {} messages {}",TAG,className,methodName,messages.toString())
            Class.forName(className)."$methodName"(messages)
        } catch (Exception exception){
            logger.error("{} [{}] Error while executing method : {} of class: {} with params : {} - {}", TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName(), methodName,
                    className, messages.toString(), exception.getStackTrace().join("\n"))
        }
        logger.debug("{} [executeConsumerMethod] Exit",TAG)
    }

    private void publishAllKafkaTopicBatchMessages(){
        logger.debug("{} [publishAllKafkaTopicBatchMessages] Enter",TAG)
        String consumerClassName = null
        String consumerMethodName = null
        kafkaTopicMessageListMap.each { topicName,messageList ->
            DBObject kafkaTopicDBObject = kafkaTopicConfigMap.get(topicName)
            consumerClassName = kafkaTopicDBObject.get(KafkaTopicConfigEntity.CLASS_NAME_KEY)
            consumerMethodName = kafkaTopicDBObject.get(KafkaTopicConfigEntity.METHOD_NAME_KEY)
            logger.debug("{} Pushing message in topic {} className {} methodName {} ",TAG,topicName,consumerClassName,consumerMethodName)
            if(messageList != null && messageList.size() > 0){
                executeConsumerMethod(consumerClassName, consumerMethodName, messageList)
                messageList.clear()
                kafkaTopicMessageListMap.put(topicName,messageList)
            }
        }
        logger.debug("{} [publishAllKafkaTopicBatchMessages] Exit",TAG)
    }
```

Comment: It might because that partitions of topic1 are growing much faster than those of topic2, so the response limit is hit before any messages from topic2 are fetched.  You could use a random shuffle to the partitions before the FetchRequest

Comment: @amethystic thanks for the reply I didn't got you. It will be extremely helpful if you will provide an example

Comment: Did you also use kafka-clients 0.10.2 to code the consumer ?

Comment: Hi Amethystic Thanks for the reply yes i used kafka 0.10.2 to code the consumer I am attaching my consumer code with my query .

Comment: Could you set `max.poll.records` to a little larger and retry? The config controls the max number of records each poll call. A larger value gives more chance to have the other topic consumed.